# Save blob to DB using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, blob

I tried save file to MySQL using blob with hibernate3. But I always have 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Blob may not be manipulated from creating session
 org.hibernate.lob.BlobImpl.excep(BlobImpl.java:127)

Here some code.

```
package com.uni.domain;

public class File extends Identifier {

    private byte[] data;
    private String contentType;

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public File() {}

    public void setData(byte[] photo) {
        this.data = photo;
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }
}

package com.uni.domain;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PhotoType implements UserType {

    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{Types.BLOB};
    }

    public Class returnedClass() {
        return byte[].class;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o, Object o1) throws HibernateException {
        return Arrays.equals((byte[]) o, (byte[]) o1);
    }

    public int hashCode(Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return o.hashCode();
    }

    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] strings, Object o) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob(strings[0]);
        return blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
    }

    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        st.setBlob(index, Hibernate.createBlob((byte[]) value));
    }

    public Object deepCopy(Object value) {
        if (value == null) return null;

        byte[] bytes = (byte[]) value;
        byte[] result = new byte[bytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, result, 0, bytes.length);

        return result;
    }

    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    public Serializable disassemble(Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return null;  .
    }

    public Object assemble(Serializable serializable, Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return null;  .
    }

    public Object replace(Object o, Object o1, Object o2) throws HibernateException {
        return null;  .
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.uni.domain">
    <class name="com.uni.domain.File">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="data" type="com.uni.domain.FleType"/>
        <property name="contentType"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Help me please. Where I’m wrong?

Comment: Your mapping shows a com.uni.domain.FleType, yet your class is named PhotoType. Was it a typo?
Can you post your stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the hibernate source code for  **BlobImpl**, you'll find that the method **getBytes** is not implemented, and only forward to exception :

```
  69    /**
   70        * @see java.sql.Blob#getBytes(long, int)
   71        */
   72       public byte[] getBytes(long pos, int len) throws SQLException {
   73           excep(); return null;
   74       }

 126    private static void excep() {
  127           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Blob may not be manipulated from creating session");
  128       }
  129
```

instead of **getBytes**() you should use **getBinaryStream**()

Example usage:

```
    InputStream inputStream = getContent().getBinaryStream();
    int expected = inputStream.available();
    byte[] contents = new byte[expected];
    int length = inputStream.read(contents);
    if(length != expected)
            throw new IOException("Could not read full input");
```

Comment: Would be nice to have some indication as to how getBinaryStream should be used.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using it with Spring, there is in-built support in Spring for it. [DefaultLobHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/DefaultLobHandler.html) It's a matter of config to get it working. [Sample Code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0417__Spring/UseLobHandlerToHandleLargeChunkofData.htm) to refer, not much has changed from the older versions of Spring.